# ExecutionQuery returns 0 even though a processInstance is currently running

Tags: execution, activiti, bpmn

I'm trying to get a specific Execution from a running process. In order to assure that there is nothing wrong with the filtering, I used a very simple query. All active Executions should be found. Exactly 1.

```
mProcessEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
          .createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration()
          .buildProcessEngine();

RepositoryService repositoryService = mProcessEngine.getRepositoryService();
repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource( processFilePath).deploy();

Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
RuntimeService runService = mProcessEngine.getRuntimeService();

ProcessInstance processInstance = runService.startProcessInstanceByKey( processId, variableMap);
List <Execution> executions = runService.createExecutionQuery().list();
```

The process instance gets started correctly, 2 tasks are executed until the process is waiting for a signal. This works as expected. But I don't get why the execution list is empty. If I query the Historic instances I get one result (as expected):

```
HistoryService historyService = mProcessHandler.getProcessEngine().getHistoryService();
List<HistoricProcessInstance> allInstances = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().list();
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the query?

---

**Update**
I figured out that the execution list is empty (even after waiting for seconds) if the execution is waiting for a boundary event signal. If the boundary event is removed the execution list returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is just wild guess. Why you are getting RuntimeService on different ways, are you sure that those runtime services are same. Try to use same `runSerivice`

```
    ...  
    Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    RuntimeService runService = mProcessEngine.getRuntimeService();  
    ProcessInstance processInstance = runService.startProcessInstanceByKey( processId, variableMap);

    List <Execution> executions = runService.createExecutionQuery().list();
```

**UPDATE**

I have just tried this and works correctly on my machine with my activti process engine(custom configuration), didn't try with test engine(createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration). Maybe you are fetching executions too early, so they are not started yet. Check if you have async flag set on your first task in process or try to delay fetching of the executions list.

I have no more ideas, so if nothing helps let me know to delete post, maybe someone else has better idea.

Comment: This is what I already do. I cleared up the code a little bit

Comment: Petar is almost certainly correct, there is a race condition happening here. The execution will not start immediately.

Comment: But why is it possible to get the historic instances at this point? This works fine.

I tried to use another Process for a test and I get the list of started instances as expected. None of the tasks is set to async. 
I still try to figure out why these issues appear with the specific process...

Comment: Try to read about transactions in Activiti, because async=true is just one way of creating new execution. http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnConcurrencyAndTransactions

Comment: I added an update to my post. Guess I have to have another look into the documentation now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What will happen if you run; runService.createExecutionQuery().signalEventSubscriptionName("yourSignalName").list();
When you have boundary signal attached.

Comment: It returns also 0. I guess this is because there is no further wait entity. 

The link that you posted clears things up: _"A wait state is a task which is performed "later" which means that Activiti persists the current execution and waits to be triggered again"_.
This explains why no execution is active. I also posted a question in the activiti forum to clear this up.